# Reduce the space allowed for the footer space when put a figure in horizontal alignement

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, figure-placement

I am using the [Springer Nature template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd) and when I put an image into horizontal alignment with the package `lscape` the position of the footer increase.
[image: Page with horizontal positioning]
While the footer is usually lower, as you can see in the following example :
[image]

My goal is to fixed that issue by keeping the horizontal alignment but reducing the size of the footer. I stress the fact, I do not want the page to have a landscape orientation.  I have tried to fix that with the package `geometry`

```
\usepackage[paperheight=16cm,paperwidth=12cm,textwidth=10cm]{geometry}
```

But I have a `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.` I suppose it enter in conflict with another set-up, but I do not know which one.

The code I used for the insertion of the figure:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\caption{\label{BlaBla}\lipsum[1-1]}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{Results/Bla/BlaBla.pdf}
\end{figure*}
\end{landscape}
```

I set my package in `\documentclass[sn-apa,iicol,Numbered]{sn-jnl}` to have double columns document and I have added the following packages to the template:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}%footnote at the bottom
\usepackage{lscape} %lanscape
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} %Only for the example
```

I have also tried as well with the package `pdflscape` but the result is similar.